# Some proof of the $\det(AB)=\det(A)\det(B)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

I saw the following proof of the $\det(AB)=\det(A)\det(B)$ as follows in Gilbert Strang's book:

> We consider the ratio $d(A) = \det AB/\det B$. Then certainly $d(I) = \det B/\det B = 1$. If two rows of $A$ are exchanged, so are the same two rows of $AB$, and the sign of $d$ changes. And a linear combination appearing in the first row of $A$ gives the same linear combination in the first row of $AB$. Therefore divided by the fixed quantity $\det B$, leads to property for the ratio $d(A)$. Thus $d(A)$ coincides with the determinant. That means $\det AB/\det B = \det A$.

It is difficult to understand what this sentence says: a linear combination appearing in the first row of $A$ gives the same linear combination in the first row of $AB$.

Does it show that the function $d(X)=\det XB/\det B$ has multilinearity? How does this process show that we get $\det A$? I'd like to express his proof with formulas.

Comment: (fyi, Strang has many books so its not clear which one you are referring to)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that book, probably, the author has shown before that the determinant is the only multilinear map
$$
det:\mathbb{R}^n\times \ldots \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}
$$
satisfying $det(e_1,\ldots,e_n)=1$, being $e_i$ the rows of $I$.

With this fact in mind, to prove $det(AB)=det(A)det(B)$, he defines this other map $d$ and check it satisfies these two conditions (multilinearity and $d(I)=1$. So he concludes that $d=det$ and therefore
$$
det(A)=d(A)=det(AB)/det(B)
$$
so
$$
det(A)det(B)=det(AB).
$$

It is a classical trick in mathematics.

**Added**: for the formulation required in the comment. Sorry for the bad presentation, but I am in a hurry.

Let $A=(r_1,\ \cdots,\ r_n)^T,\ B=(c_1,\ \cdots,\ c_n),\ (AB)_{ij}=r_ic_j $

If $A_1=(\alpha_1 s_1+\alpha_2s_2)$
$$(AB)_1=((\alpha_1s_1+\alpha_2s_2)c_1,\ \cdots,\ (\alpha_1s_1+\alpha_2s_2)c_n)=(\alpha_1g_1+\alpha_2g_2)$$

$g_1=(s_1c_1,\ s_1c_2,\ \cdots,\ s_1c_n),\ g_2=(s_2c_1,\ s_2c_2,\ \cdots,\ s_2c_n)$

Comment: I have edited the question. Sorry but I have to go. Let me know if you can't get it.